# What expression should I use in this case?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

In Italian, when somebody wants to say that something is true also for them, or they know something because they experienced the same, they sometimes say *non lo dire a me* (litrerally, "don't say it to me"). For example, that could be the answer to the following sentences.

> I pay too much for the property taxes!

> The gasoline price got raised again!

> I feel cold!

> I would smoke a cigarette right now!

What would an equivalent expression be, in English?

The implicit phrase for the Italian expression is "because I know it well"; the other person experienced (or is experiencing) the same.

I thought to "Don't tell me!" but that sounds like the other person doesn't want to speak about that topic, maybe because the topic is not of any interest, but that is not the case for the Italian expression.

Comment: In the US the expression is the exact opposite: "***Tell*** me about it!" with the first word, and only the first word, strongly emphasized in stress and pitch. The sense, I think, is "I'm happy to hear you say that because I feel exactly the same and I have an even better story to tell you!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As StoneyB mentioned in comments, I think the closest phrase to your original is

> *Tell* me about it!

Also as Stoney said, *tell* is italicized here because it is stressed. Though the words instruct the other person to tell you more, the implication is actually that they don't need to; what you mean when you say this is "You could tell me more about this, but actually you don't have to... I'm already very aware of the subject and completely agree with you."

That's the most directly related phrase to your original Italian, but you might also consider this:

> No kidding!

This wouldn't always apply in 100% of the same situations, but the basic idea is "Yeah, I know exactly what you mean! You're completely right." This is a bit more informal, though.

For example:

> Wow, did you see the kids? They grow up so fast!
>
> Tell me about it!

("I know they do, you're right; I'm totally agreeing with your amazement!")

> Did you see those gas prices? When gas costs more than milk...
>
> Ha. No kidding.

("You're right, that's crazy. Gas prices really are insanely high.")

Comment: There's also, "Don't I know it"

Answer (score 2):

A common idiom/expression for this is:

**"You can say THAT again!"**

It is another way of saying, "I agree with you 100%." The emphasis is on "that."

Additionally,

**"You said it!"**

Again, pretty much just saying "I agree with what you just said very strongly."

Another possibility:

**"You're preaching to the choir"**

You don't have to convince me - I am a firm believer in that. (It is assumed that the choir of the church is already convinced of the ideas, so you don't need to spend as much effort preaching to them). This is more about trying to convince someone of a point or idea - you wouldn't use this as a response to "I'm cold."

Answer (score 1):

> "Petrol prices are getting ridiculous!"
>
> **You're telling me!**

> I'm drowning in a sea of debt
>
> **You're not the only one!**

> Taxes, inflation, unemployment rising... Could life get any worse?
>
> **"You bet!"** or **"You better believe it!"**

> I'd kill for another cigarette
>
> **Me too!** OR **"Ack, don't even go there!"**

Actually I am the only person I know who says "ack" but it's very versatile. It's slightly Scottish in *flavour*, throaty and dry, as if you wanted to spit but you can't manage to.

Answer (score 0):

Another common slang phrase that is used mostly by younger people is "I know, *right*?" or sometimes just "*Right*?"  The emphasis is on "right" and indicates your agreement, the correctness of the statement, and/or your incredulity at the situation.

I can't believe how hard that test was!
--I know, right?  I'm sure that I failed.

Wow, you weren't kidding. They look exactly alike!
--Right?!  I couldn't believe it!